# Strange behavior of custom UITableViewCell label

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why, but my label behaves strangely. You can check screenshots bellow. Image should fill stackView.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um1z9.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code, what are you doing there and what you want to achieve. Then anyone can help you with your problem.

Comment: Also don't ask your question as image files. Explain your problem clearly and use your image as a supplement.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @bisma. It's storyboard issue

Answer (score 1):

Since you really ought to share a bit more, I can only try to answer based on what's available.

The problem is most likely due to the fact that the StackView that surrounds the label and image does not have a width or height constraint of any sort and/or the imageView has a very low content compression resistance property.

Because StackViews calculate their size based on their child views, it will try to find the best fit. If the label has a normal compression resistance but the imageView has its resistance set to low, the stackView will simply calculate its frame based on the label alone.

So to fix it check the compression resistance of those objects or define contraints for the surrounding stackView to match its parents width.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly.. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Image and Text one beside the other, or one below the other? You might want to check for the stackview direction property

Secondly if you want that your image size remains constant, you will have to give your image view some fixed width constraint, and stackview will respect the size of the imageview. Or if you want that the image takes the entire width of the screen, you can basically pin the stackview to the edges of the screen, after you have put in the imageview inside of the stackview.

Hope that makes sense.
Comment back if you need more help :)